# Prevent Closure Compiler from renaming properties without using bracket notation

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm working on a product which needs to conditionally expose an API to the end user. We're using the Closure Compiler for minification. The part of the API that I'm trying to expose is a function that calls a callback with a `Result` whose value is an object with certain properties.

Specifically, the function I'm trying to expose looks like this (in pseudo-jsdoc notation):

```
/**
 * @type DocumentRenderResult {status: String, image?: HTMLImageElement|HTMLCanvasElement}
 * @param {function(Result<DocumentRenderResult>)} callback
**/
function renderDocument (url, page, callback) {

}
```

And the `Result` class looks like this:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {Boolean} ok
 * @param {T} val
 * @param {Error} err
**/
function Result (ok, val, err) {
    this.ok = ok;
    this.val = val;
    this.err = err;
}
```

What I'd like is to expose both the `Result` object API - that is, the fact that there are `ok`, `val`, and `err` properties, and expose the `renderDocument` interface so that users providing a callback will be able to access the `status` and `image` properties.

One solution (possibly) is to use bracket notation everywhere, but since this is supposed to be only *conditionally* exposed (for certain end users), I'd like to separate the concept of whether it's minified or not from the code.

I think some combination of @implements and @export and an externs file can accomplish this, but I haven't figured it out.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: This seems like a design smell; it doesn't really make sense for a library to *sometimes* provide a function and *sometimes* not.

Comment: I get your point, but it's not a library actually. It's a proprietary product which would offer a rendering library as an extension to its main feature. Normally it's all wrapped in an IIFE to prevent scope leakage, but for certain customers (including for another product of ours) we would expose these functions to global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 primary ways to handle this situation:

#### Without Closure-Library

Store all of your exports in a separate file that becomes the main entry point for the api exposed library. This methodology has no dependencies on external libraries. For an example of this, see my [GeolocationMarker library](https://github.com/ChadKillingsworth/geolocation-marker/blob/master/src/geolocation-marker-exports.js).

#### With Closure-Library (or at least a part of it)

If you are willing to utilize a very small part of closure-library code in your project, you can use the `@export` annotation. `@export` annotations do nothing unless the compilation flag `--generate_exports` is specified.

When `--generate_exports` is used, the compiler will add the appropriate call to either closure-library's goog.exportProperty or goog.exportSymbol method.

```
/** @const */
var mynamespace = {};

/** @export */
mynamespace.maybeExposedMethod = function() {};
```

With the `--generate_exports` flag, the compiler will generate the code:

```
var mynamespace = {maybeExposedMethod:function() {}};
goog.exportSymbol("mynamespace.maybeExposedMethod",
    mynamespace.maybeExposedMethod);
```

Instead of having to depend on all of closure-library. You can copy the definition for those 2 methods into your source. All that's needed is that they exist as those names.

#### Conditionally Renaming Record Types

Functions which return anonymous objects must be treated differently to prevent renaming. The best option here would be to define a record type in its own file. For the public api to block renaming, include the record definition as an extern. When you want the record properties to be renamed, include the definition as source.

**my_typedefs.js**

```
/** @typedef {{image: string, status: number}} */
var my_record_type;
```

**my_method_def.js**

```
/** @return {my_record_type} */
function my_method() {
  return {
    image: 'some_image.jpg',
    status: 200
  };
}
```

If `my_typedefs.js` is included in the compilation with the `--js` flag, the record properties will be renamed, but if it is included with the `--externs` flag, they will not be renamed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's great to hear an answer from someone who knows Closure so well. Is there a way to adapt the method you've outlined above to expose properties of an object returned by a function? E.g. I want to keep the properties exposed in something like `return {image: someVal, status: someVal}`. Can I define an API representing the return value type somewhere so that it stays exposed?

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton I've edited the answer to include that case.

Comment: Thank you! The ability to conditionally include that extern file is perfect for what I'm trying to do.